# Matrix: put only negative value on the diagonal position in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have a question about rearranging a numpy array, I have a numpy array, it looks like this:

```
numpy_array = np.array([[  1,   2,   3,   4, -10],
                        [ -4,   1,   1,   1,   1],
                        [  2,  -7,   1,   1,   3],
                        [  1,   6, -12,   2,   3],
                        [  0,   3,   1,  -4,   0]])
```

I would like to rearrange this array: the negative value on each row will be on the diagonal position, that is to say, swap the negative element with the element on the diagonal position, so I get a new array at the end like this:

```
numpy_array_new = np.array([[-10,   2,   3,   4,   1],
                            [  1,  -4,   1,   1,   1],
                            [  2,   1,  -7,   1,   3],
                            [  1,   6,   2, -12,   3],
                            [  0,   3,   1,   0,  -4]])
```

my idea is to use

```
np.fill_diagonal(numpy_array, 0)
```

of course fill diagonal with negative elements not with 0, but with negative element in each row, someone knows about this? Thanks for helping

Comment: what happens when there are more than one negative in a row?

Comment: there would be only one negative element in a row for my case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that there is only one negative value in a row.

Following code returns the matrix you want without any for loop.

```
# Find negative elements and their index in a row 
negative_indices =np.where(arr < 0)
negative_elements = arr[negative_indices]
diagonal_elements = arr.diagonal()

# Change negative elements with current diagonal values 
arr[negative_indices] = diagonal_elements 

# Fill diagonal with the negative elements
np.fill_diagonal(arr, negative_elements)

print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way based on swapping of items at specific indices:

```
idx_of_negatives = np.where(numpy_array < 0) 
# it's a tuple ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 0, 1, 2, 3])

idx_of_diagonal = (np.arange(len(numpy_array)), np.arange(len(numpy_array)))
# it's a tuple ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

numpy_array[idx_of_negatives], numpy_array[idx_of_diagonal] = 
numpy_array[idx_of_diagonal], numpy_array[idx_of_negatives]
```